# What are the best audio-settings when recording video on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, video, avfoundation

I want to record the best possible quality for audio **when recording video**. I guess that would mean 'no compression' for the audio. However, I still have to set compression-settings for the audio-track, and I can't find the combination I should use. On all examples I can find, they've set it to MPEG4/MPEG4AAC/H.264 for the entire recording.

This is working(simplified):

```
NSDictionary *audioCompressionSettings = 
   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC, AVFormatIDKey,
        44100.0, AVSampleRateKey,
        128000, AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey,
        1, AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
        currentChannelLayoutData, AVChannelLayoutKey,
        nil];
```

In the code above, I choose MPEG4AAC as codec for the audio. However, I want to try to use a lossless format, to see if that gets better sound (e.g recording instruments or other music etc, with built-in-mic/headphones, or even 3rd-party equipment connected). For the video, I'm using `AVVideoCodecH264` for the `AVVideoCodecKey`, and I guess this could be part of the problem, but I don't know where to look for solutions.

As I understand, iPhones arent able to record higher than 44.1khz, but I know nothing of the bitrate or other settings. If I simply change the format from `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` to `kAudioFormatAppleLossless` or `kAudioFormatLinearPCM`, it won't record. It seems they aren't compatible with the other settings.

What combination should I use for recording video, when I want the absolute top quality audio(and when file size isn't a factor)?

Comment: This is a year ago now, but I would love to know if you did find a way to record really high quality audio with video?  Ive been comparing the audio quality in my video recordings to the standard iphone audio recorder, and its terrible!  Any help would be great, thanks